# Point a domain to another domain

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, parking

What I want to do is, I want to point my domain which I registered from Dot TK ( a free domain registration service ) to another domain which I am currently hosting on Freeola ( a hosting service ). But I don't want to use domain parking because Freeola doesn't allow it. So I want ask if there is any other option other than parking. If parking is the only option then, can we park a domain even if the the hosting company is not allowing it?

Basically, what I want is:

If my domain name is `example.tk` and the domain which is hosted on Freeola is `example.com`
then can I do the following things:

1. When a user goes to `example.tk` the content of `example.com` is shown but the url in the address bar should remain `example.tk`.
2. When a user goes to `example.tk/sample-page` the content of `example.com/sample-page` is shown but the url in the address bar should remain `example.tk/sample-page`.

Please excuse me if this is a silly question because I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your domain manager (wherever you bought the domain name from), and set the CNAME alias of example.tk to example.com.

It make may take some fiddling but i'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> When a user goes to example.tk the content of example.com is shown but the url in the address bar should not change.

Though not recommended, you can use frames. With a frame the URL will not change.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>Example</title></head>
  <frameset rows="*,0">
    <frame src="http://example.com" name="frame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"/>
    <noframes><body>Your browser doesn't have support for frames!</body></noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Another alternative is a Server Alias. With a server alias, the URL will not change. The requirement is that your domain is hosted at the same server as the target. And it may negatively influence your Google ranking.

Conclusion: probably you'll have to use frames.

> Please excuse me if this is a silly question because I am just a beginner.

That's why you're here, right? :)

Comment: Extremely sorry, see my new question and change your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a very good one, very far from being silly.

What you probably need to do is to point your domain registered through http://www.dot.tk to the server where your website is hosted. By website I mean your files not the doamin name. That will be achieved by updating the DNS settings at http://www.dot.tk with nameservers associated with your website. In other words, your domain name at dot.tk should have nameservers which correspond to nameservers associated with the server where your site (files) are hosted.

Nameservers is a piece of information which looks like **rns7b.justhost.com** or **ns2.inmotionhosting.com**

If you can not locate the nameservers associated with your website, your host should be able to provide that.

Personally, my domains are registered through Enom but the sites are hosted by Inmotion Hosting. Nameservers serve as a link between my domain at Enom and the web server at Inmotion Hosting.

If you do the setup correctly, things should work as you explained you want them to work.

Please note that change of DNS settings can take time to propagate around the world. They could take up to 24 hours to fully propagate.

Good luck.

Comment: According to you, what I have to do is just change the name servers? By the way, I forgot to tell you that Freeola doesn't support tk domains.